Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RCTVideo
I'm encountering an error with two video packages, "react-native-af-video-player" and "react-native-video." Even after deleting the node modules, the error persists on both screens. I expected the error to be fixed after deleting the node modules, but it remains unresolved.

can you please share the error

@WaseemKurne I get this error: Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RCTVideo
in AppNavigator from two screen

You can use only package of both as they are using same native module packages. So uninstall any one package.
